# CLI login issue

Tags: nvidia, login, login-screen

A failed graphic card update has led me to this. I can login to either of the local system user accounts shown on the GUI screen but when this is done, the screen flashes black and then I am returned to the login page. When I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up the terminal and try to login using either of those same accounts that succeed through the GUI I am given a "Login incorrect" error when trying to login. I don't have a way to login, so I can't reset the driver or push an update through.

I know the accounts and passwords are good because the login process is started when I try either one on through the GUI. I don't get the "Invalid password, please try again" failure. Just the flash to a black screen and then back to the login screen.

Anyone have any ideas or other things I could try?

Comment: Can you boot to recovery or single user mode through grub?

Comment: Its weird that you are not able to login through the terminal. You should be able to do that. In the past, I have come across the same issue, but was able to login through terminal. Pls look at syslog `/var/log/syslog` and paste/search for the error you get during login. If you are not able to login through terminal then look at syslog from live boot (although switching between GUI and terminal will help you pinpoint the cause)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was on a work trip and that delayed my access to this system. I am unable to login using any account via the terminal. And when I login via the GUI I just get the black screen and then back to the GUI login screen. Is there a way to update my installation on the disk having booting into a live boot instance?